# How to send periodic tasks to specific queue in Celery

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

By default Celery send all tasks to 'celery' queue, but you can change this behavior by adding extra parameter:

```
@task(queue='celery_periodic')
def recalc_last_hour():
    log.debug('sending new task')
    recalc_hour.delay(datetime(2013, 1, 1, 2)) # for example
```

Scheduler settings:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'installer_recalc_hour': {
        'task': 'stats.installer.tasks.recalc_last_hour',
        'schedule': 15  # every 15 sec for test
    },
}
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
```

Run worker:

```
python manage.py celery worker -c 1 -Q celery_periodic -B -E
```

This scheme doesn't work as expected: this workers sends periodic tasks to 'celery' queue, not 'celery_periodic'. How can I fix that?

P.S. celery==3.0.16

Comment: can this be helpful? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html

Comment: I turned off option CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER (used file based stoprage) and it works correctly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found solution for this problem:

1) First of all I changed the way for configuring periodic tasks. I used **@periodic_task** decorator like this:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='5'),
               queue='celery_periodic',
               options={'queue': 'celery_periodic'})
def recalc_last_hour():
    dt = datetime.utcnow()
    prev_hour = datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour) \
                - timedelta(hours=1)
    log.debug('Generating task for hour %s', str(prev_hour))
    recalc_hour.delay(prev_hour)
```

2) I wrote **celery_periodic** twice in params to **@periodic_task**:

- **queue='celery_periodic'** option is used when you invoke task from code (.delay or .apply_async)
- **options={'queue': 'celery_periodic'}** option is used when *celery beat* invokes it.

I'm sure, the same thing is possible if you'd configure periodic tasks with CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE variable.

UPD. This solution correct for both DB based and file based storage for **CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER**.

Comment: @periodic_task (if I get it right) are deprecated right now

Comment: Can you please share how to refactor the same code for celery v5.1.2? (because periodic_task decorator has been deprecated)

Answer (score 63):

Periodic tasks are sent to queues by celery beat where you can do everything you do with the Celery API. Here is the list of configurations that comes with celery beat:

https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#available-fields

In your case:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'installer_recalc_hour': {
        'task': 'stats.installer.tasks.recalc_last_hour',
        'schedule': 15,  # every 15 sec for test
        'options': {'queue' : 'celery_periodic'},  # options are mapped to apply_async options
    },
}
```

Comment: Well, both answer the question in a way... However, I agree that this answer is slightly better than the accepted one because the question author asked for CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE change...

Answer (score 2):

And if you are using djcelery Database scheduler, you can specify the queue on the Execution Options -> queue field